# An expression of non-boolean type specified in the context where condition is expected in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, t-sql

i want to use following SQL query for displaying records but i am getting error below DropDate

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in the context where
>   condition is expected

Here is my query

```
Select rm.RoomID,rm.RoomNo,rd.CheckIn,rd.CheckOut,ity.ItemTypeName,ln.ReservationID,g.GuestID,g.GuestName,ln.LaundryID,it.ItemName,ln.PickDate,ln.ServiceKind,l     n.DropQty,ln.DropDate from Laundry ln 
inner join Items it on ln.ItemId = it.ItemId
inner join ItemTypes ity on ity.ItemTypeId = it.ItemTypeId 
inner join Rooms rm on ln.RoomID = rm.RoomID
left join Reservation_Guest rg on rg.ReservationID = ln.ReservationID 
left join ReservationDetails rd on rd.ReservationID = ln.ReservationID 
left join Guests g on g.GuestID = rg.GuestID where PickDate is not null 
and DropDate and OutDate is null
```

I am getting error from DropDate i want display records with PickDate is not null and DropDate and OutDate is null
Please suggest me any better way.

Comment: I assume you want `and DropDate is null and OutDate is null`. You have to check each field individually.

Comment: Could be a typo, but also take a look at the spacing or tab  "l        n.DropQty"

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server doesn't support boolean types.  And, it doesn't convert values to boolean expressions.  Presumably, you intend something like:

```
and DropDate is null and OutDate is null
-------------^ or whatever condition you want
```